# Kivy filechooser on_selection no trigger event

Tags: kivy

Kivy 2.0
I am not using kv format only python scripts.

```
        self.fileBrowser = FileChooserIconView(# select_string='Select', dirselect: True
              # path='projects/' + self.engineConfig.currentProjectName + '/data/',
              filters=['*.png', '*.jpg'],
              path= drives[1] + '/',
              size_hint=(1,3),
              on_selection=fileBrowserSelected,
              on_release=fileBrowserSelected,
              on_press=fileBrowserSelected
              on_submit=self.load_from_filechooser
           )
        self.rightBox.add_widget(self.fileBrowser)

        #self.fileBrowser.bind(on_press=partial(self.fileBrowserSelected))
        self.fileBrowser.bind(on_submit=partial(self.load_from_filechooser))

        self.rightBox.add_widget(Label(text='Application assets pack path'))
```

I try pratial , local def with self.method .

Only on_submit work on double click.

Any Suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Try binding your functions like this:

```
self.fileBrowser = FileChooserIconView(# select_string='Select', dirselect: True
          # path='projects/' + self.engineConfig.currentProjectName + '/data/',
          filters=['*.png', '*.jpg'],
          path= drives[1] + '/',
          size_hint=(1,3),
          on_selection=lambda a: self.fileBrowserSelected(),
          on_release=lambda a: self.fileBrowserSelected(),
          on_press=lambda a: self.fileBrowserSelected(),
          on_submit=self.load_from_filechooser
       )
```

Comment: Still no trigger not errors but not event `on_selection` .

Comment: That's odd. Any way you could post a reproducible example?

Comment: I did it with : `self.fileBrowser.bind(selection=partial(self.load_from_filechooser))` my wrong attempt was ``self.fileBrowser.bind(on_selection=partial(self.load_from_filechooser))``  Thks for sharing  and assist.

Comment: Sure, glad you figured it out!